# OneupUploaderBundle: Render response message in twig template

Tags: symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I use the OneupUploaderBundle in my project to upload files.

My question is:

How can i render the response.msg from the UploadListener in my twig template? How can I evaluate my response.

https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/response.md

//service.yml

```
acme.upload_listener:
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, method: onUpload }
```

//UploadListener.php

```
class UploadListener
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->set('file', $file->getPathName());

        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $response['msg'] = "File stored in session";

        => show response.msg in my twig-template. But how?
    }
}
```

//JS (in twig template)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({});
```

I have no examples found...

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't do this in your Twig template. The Twig templates are rendered on page load and the file upload is done using Ajax. What you can do is altering the DOM in javascript.

For example:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({}).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $("body").prepend('<p>File stored in session</p>');
});
```

You can also send some data back to the client:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({}).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    if (data.result.filename != undefined) {
        $("body").prepend('<p>File ' + data.result.filename + ' stored in session</p>');
    }
});
```

But in order to do that, you need to create an event listener for the `oneup_uploader.post_persist` event that will send the filename back with the response, as explained in the documentation to which you linked.

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;

class UploadListener
{
    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $files = $request->files->get('files');
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $filename = $files[0]->getClientOriginalName();
        $response['filename'] = $filename;
    }
}
```

In your services.yaml:

```
# Event listener to handle uploaded files
foobar.upload_listener:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onUpload }
```